# Is it possible to use Visual Studio 2015 and VMware without enabling or disabling Hyper-V?

Tags: visual-studio

I try to debug Visual C# project on Visual Studio and I keep getting an error message related to Hyper-V.

It works as soon as I enable Hyper-V but then I cannot use VMware.

I don't know why Visual Studio requires Hyper-V but is there any way that I can use both Visual Studio and VMware? Restarting a computer every time I change the setting is bit annoying.